# Http Listener vs Web Api for insert in SqlServer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, httplistener

I'm using a very simple software. My only need is to send via a mobile phone a query in a local computer (through wifi), and then application to execute my query.

I found two methods but i dont know which of them match better in my needs.
Both methods which i will describe run locally in my computer.

## Method One Http Listener:

```
HttpListener listener;
Thread t;
   
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(MyThreadMethod));
        t.IsBackground = true;
        listener = new HttpListener();
        listener.Prefixes.Add("http://192.168.0.214:8282/");
        listener.Start();
        t.Start();
       
}
void MyThreadMethod()
{
    while (true)
    {
         IAsyncResult result = listener.BeginGetContext(new AsyncCallback(ListenerCallback), listener);
            result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(30000);
    }
}

public void ListenerCallback(IAsyncResult result)
{
       
        string Response = "";
        try
        {
           
           
            HttpListener listener = (HttpListener)result.AsyncState;
            HttpListenerContext context = listener.EndGetContext(result);
            var SqlData = new StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream,context.Request.ContentEncoding).ReadToEnd();

            string connectionString = "Server=(local);Database=xxxx;User id=admin;password=1234;";
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (SqlCommand ReceiveData = new SqlCommand(SqlData, connection))
                    ReceiveData.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Response = "OK";

            }
            HttpListenerResponse response = context.Response;
            string responseString = Convert.ToString(Response);
            byte[] buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseString);
            response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;
            System.IO.Stream output = response.OutputStream;
            output.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            output.Close();
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {

      using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\LogFile.txt"))
      {
          file.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(ex));
      }
```

This method is running  in my local computer as an *.exe or cmd or as windows service.

## Method 2 Asp Net Web Api:(I'm creating a controller named InsertData)

```
  public class InsertDataController : ApiController
  {

    // POST: api/InsertData
    public string Post(HttpContent httpContent)
    {
        var readAsStringAsync = httpContent.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var SqlData = readAsStringAsync.Result;

        string connectionString = "Server=(local);Database=xxxx;User id=admin;password=1234;";
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (SqlCommand ReceiveData = new SqlCommand(SqlData, connection))
                ReceiveData.ExecuteNonQuery();
           
        }
        return "OK";
    }
```

I notice that asp net it's some milliseconds slower than http listener. But it seems more stable with shorter code. Also asp net is running through IIS7 and httplistener as an *.exe or cmd or windows service.
But which of methods is more stable, and stands better in my case? I don't need something more than sending simple strings.

Comment: For a personal/local app for Study purpose choose anyone which is quicker to implement. HttpListener approach doesnt have any infra dependencies. While for ASP.NET MVC WebAPi you will need to host it somewhere (Self Hosted --> HttpListener or IIS).

Comment: So for a simple string it is better to go with HttpListener?